# Expression Web 4: Open visual studio 2010 CSPROJ ? or SLN?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, expression-blend, expression-web

I have recently started to use Web Expression 4. I was under the impression that you can open CSPROJ / SLN in Expression web 4.

When i click File Open I can see both the SLN and the CSPROJ ... but if i choose either it autoamtically loads visual studio 2010.

I thought you could open both??

I want to use expression web 4 for designing my html pages that are in my VS 2010 project.

But of course i want to open the project so i can see all my CSS files and create new ones etc..

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

The folder list (on the left) in expression web 4 is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you could in your Expression Web are the ASP.NET web pages (.aspx) and the like.
According to [Jim Chesire](http://social.expression.microsoft.com/profile/jim%20cheshire/):

> A solution file is simply a "pointer"
>   to your content. Expression Web has no
>   understanding of solution files. When
>   you open the site in Expression Web,
>   you need to open the location of your
>   content, not the location of the
>   solution file.